# For any polynomial f(x) with integer coefficients, is it possible that the the greatest prime factor of f(x) can be arbitrary small?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Recently I found a problem about elementary number theory: Let $f(x)=x^2+x+1$,prove that there are infinite $n\in N$ so that the the greatest prime factor of $f(n)$ is less than $n^{1.1}$.

The answer is easy. We only need to take $n=m^2$,so $f(n)=(m^2+m+1)(m^2-m+1)$.For sufficiently large $m$,the conclusion is obvious.

**Question**.For any given polynomial $f(x)\in Z[x]$ and any given positive real number $a$,are there infinite $n\in N$ so that the greatest prime factor of $f(n)$ is less than $n^a$？

**Remark**.The original question is for some specific polynomial like $x^k-1$,and in this case I know the proposition is true which can be proved through the cyclotomic polynomial. But for any $f(x)\in Z[x]$,I don't know whether it is correct.

I tried to prove that we can always take some n  with some special forms such as $n=m^2$ like what I did before so that $f(n)$ can be a reducible polynomial. I succeeded in proving it but finally I failed because I didn't know how to deal with the factor of $f(n)$ after the factorization.

Although the tags include "elementary number theory", I think this question might be quiet difficult and not an elementary question. So if anyone can give the answer or give some advice, I would be grateful.

**PS**.I'm going to post my proof below when $f(x)=x^k-1$.

Let $n=y^m$, and then $f(n)=y^{mk}-1$. Let $\Phi_i(x)$ be the i-th cyclotomic  polynomial so we have $f(n)=\Pi_{d|mk}\Phi_d(y)$

The Maximum degree of $\Phi_d(y)$ is $\phi (mk)$, so we only need to prove  $\phi (mk)<am$. Assume $(k,m)=1$, so the inequality is$\frac{\phi (m)}{m}<\frac{a}{\phi (k)}$. In fact the LHS can be  arbitrary small for we know that reciprocal sum of all prime numbers is  divergent . Take $m=p_1p_2......p_r$ where $p_i$ are different prime numbers and r is a sufficiently large number, we get the conclusion.

Comment: A consequence of Rouché’s theorem is that it provides a short proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra, with explicit bound on how large the roots are. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem

Comment: @vvg I know this theorem, but I still don't know how it can help to solve this question. Could you tell me in detail?

Comment: How does the proof look for, say, $f(x) = x^2-1$? I'm not seeing an obvious way to get $a$ much smaller than $1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Setting $x = m^k$ allows you to factor $f(m^k)$ into factors that are $O(m^{\phi(k)})$, and $\phi(k)$ can be made arbitrarily small relative to $k$ (e.g. consider a sequences of $k$s taken from the primorials).

Comment: @BenjaminWright I add my proof when $f(x)=x^k-1$.You can see it and give some advice.

Answer (score 7):

We conjecture that the answer is yes, but for most polynomials this is still an open problem. I have a [2018 paper with Bober, Fretwell, and Wooley](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Egerg/papers/downloads/SVP.pdf) that I believe is still the state of the art on this topic. We prove that the answer is yes for quadratic polynomials (Corollary 1.2) and for any polynomial that is the product of binomials (Theorem 2.1; this uses the cyclotomic argument the OP described). For other polynomials, we can prove this not for all positive $a$ but only when $a$ exceeds some function of the degree of $f$; our paper describes such results (where we mildly strengthen some results of Schinzel) as well.